# Forecasting time series with LSTM using CNTK

Tags: time-series, lstm, cntk

I read a [post](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Tutorial/Forecasting-Short-Time-Series-with-LSTM-Neural-Networks-2) about forecasting time series with LSTM using CNTK. It is very helpful for me to get better understanding of how to apply this method to tackle other problems. It is so simple to implement LSTM network using CNTK, only with a couple lines of code.

```
model = Sequential (

  RecurrentLSTMLayer {$stateDim$, usePeepholes = true} : #first LSTM

  DenseLayer {$labelDim$, bias=false}                    # followed by an adaptor layer (from LSTN output size to the output or label size)

)
```

I used the data preprocessing program included in the post to generate the training data and validation data. I tried to prepare my domain data by studing the training data file of the example, I can understand each row consists of 15 features (input window) and 12 labels (output output window). The first two rows of data shown below.

```
1|i -0.117767881389987 -0.136789685972378 -0.157142990666484 -0.110810379516591 -0.0514608885500003 -0.0519359184751851 -0.093395333203464 -0.0466859579796335 -0.027053633818924 -0.0228974319964887 -0.0226106294034727 -0.0771583282775792 0.0326521764808296 0.0382623225371779 0.0179878482650109 |o -0.0419931078602005 -0.00707823233794613 -0.0326514790959216 0.107345877141872 0.0500879860433807 -0.0227185182952923 0.0354644105738453 0.0276734047763592 0.0830922226488839 0.0670409830200276 0.0983389666100694 0.101450282120106 |
1|i -0.142277570256967 -0.162630874951073 -0.11629826380118 -0.0569487728345894 -0.0574238027597742 -0.0988832174880532 -0.0521738422642226 -0.0325415181035131 -0.0283853162810779 -0.0280985136880618 -0.0826462125621683 0.0271642921962405 0.0327744382525887 0.0124999639804217 -0.0474809921447896 |o -0.0125661166225353 -0.0381393633805107 0.101857992857283 0.0446001017587916 -0.0282064025798814 0.0299765262892562 0.02218552049177 0.0776043383642948 0.0615530987354385 0.0928510823254802 0.0959623978355166 0.0630698500493061 |
```

As mentioned in the post, Input(15 values) and output (12 values) windows move forward one step at a time(see picture below), therefore, data at each row should just shift one value at a time, but they don't appear to me that is the case. There don't seem to have any overlaps of values between two rows.

[Input and output windows for the time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IndN1.png)

My question is how should I prepare the training and validation data for time series prediction using CNTK LSTM?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the data preprocessing script (in R) and found out that values in each input and output window are sum of the smooth trend and the **random component** (noise) as part of data normalization.